# solve function of pulp library in python : Type Error: must be real number, not str

Tags: python, typeerror, pulp

Implementing Transportation problem in python

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ZMW3k-kk_0Zn6esTLPi5D9gyxWoAD4to?usp=sharing

```py
from pulp import *

destination = ["D1" , "D2" , "D3"]
origin = ["O1", "O2","O3" ,"O4"]
supply = {
    "O1" : 5,
    "O2" : 8,
    "O3" : 7,
    "O4" : 14
}

demand = {
    "D1" : 7,
    "D2" : 9,
    "D3" : 18
}

cost = {
    "O1" :{"D1" : 2 , "D2" : 7 , "D3" : 4},
    "O2" :{"D1" : 3 , "D2" : 3 , "D3" : 1},
    "O3" :{"D1" : 5 , "D2" : 4 , "D3" : 7},
    "O4" :{"D1" : 1 , "D2" : 6 , "D3" : 2}
}

prob = LpProblem("Transportation" , LpMinimize)

routes = [(i , j) for i in origin for j in destination]

route_variables = LpVariable.dicts("Route" , (origin , destination) , LpInteger)

# add the objective function in prob variable
prob += lpSum([route_variables[o][d]*cost[o][d] for (o,d) in routes])

# add the constraints in prob variable

# supply constraints
for o in origin:
    prob += lpSum([route_variables[o][d] for d in destination]) <= supply[o]
    
# demand constraints
for d in destination:
    prob += lpSum([route_variables[o][d] for o in origin]) >= demand[d]

prob.solve()
```

[image]

Whenever I run my code, this is the error I get and I don’t understand why.

Answer (score 3):

Just replace the line:

```
route_variables = LpVariable.dicts("Route" , (origin , destination) , LpInteger)
```

To:

```
route_variables = LpVariable.dicts("Route" , (origin , destination) , cat=LpInteger)
```

This is because LpVariable.dicts looks like:

```
def dicts(self, name, indexs, lowBound = None, upBound = None, cat = LpContinuous, indexStart = []):
```

Answer (score -1):

In order for the problem to be solved first the problem has to be written into an lp file. Use the statement

```
prob.writeLP("NameofFile.lp")
```

before calculating using prob.solve()

Comment: From my experimentation this is not necessary. I however find that specifying cat= with LpInteger (or LpBinary...) is needed